# How to stop docker to download everything from scratch when changing something in Dockerfile?

Tags: linux, docker

I have docker file as following:

```dockerfile
FROM alpine:3.7
# install system wide 
RUN apk update
RUN apk add alpine-sdk build-base redis
# install cmake
WORKDIR /dep
RUN wget 'https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.20.2/cmake-3.20.2.tar.gz' && tar zxvf cmake-3.20.2.tar.gz
RUN cd cmake-3.20.2 && ./bootstrap && make && sudo make install
# install redis
WORKDIR /dep
RUN git clone https://github.com/cpp-redis/cpp_redis.git --depth 1
RUN cd cpp_redis && git submodule init && git submodule update && mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release && make && sudo make install
# install libcurl
WORKDIR /dep
RUN wget 'https://curl.se/download/curl-7.76.1.tar.gz' && tar xvzf curl-7.76.1.tar.gz
RUN cd curl-7.76.1 && ./configure && make && sudo make install
# change 
WORKDIR /src
# copy the source
COPY . .
```

and I build it with `docker build . -t myimage:1.0.0` but when I want to add a new line for example `RUN apk add linux-headers` into my `Dockerfile` and `docker build . -t myimage:1.0.0` it installs everything from scratch as it didn't do it before, and it eats up my internet and waste my time waiting for downloads to complete.

My question is there any way to effectively update the docker file and rebuild it again without having to download everything from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

Docker will build its layers from a line you have changed till the end. So I think the best way for you is to make a base image for yourself for the fixed portion of Dockerfile then make changes on not fixed portion.